# DynamoDb query on stored date

Tags: graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync, dynamodb-queries

I have resolving template that will get start date as date from appsync query. But my date saved in Dynamo is having datetime stamp. How we can compare these two dates without time. Below is my resolver template query:

```
 "version": "2018-05-29",
 "operation": "Query", 
 "query": {
  "expression": "Id = :Id and startDate =:date",
  "expressionValues": {
    #set( $Id = 
      $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson("fixture#${ctx.args.input.Id}") )
    ":Id": $Id,
    #set( $date = $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($ctx.args.input.date)
    ":date": $date
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

DynamoDB does not understand dates. Based on your requirements, there are two ways you can achieve this depending upon the format of the timestamp in your DynamoDB.

1 - If you store timestamp as "milliseconds/seconds since epoch", you can convert the AWSDate (which is ISO8601) to Epoch milliseconds/seconds timestamp using

`$util.time.parseISO8601ToEpochMilliSeconds("2018-02-01T17:21:05.180+08:00")`

and then use filter with `BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate` to query your table based on the input date.
Please note that

> endDate(seconds) = startDate + 86400

or

> endDate(milliseconds) = startDate + 86400000

2 - If you use String representation of timestamp, then you might need to add Global Secondary Index (GSI) with a date field as attribute of keytype "range". There are some very good explanation and suggested solution on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836600/querying-dynamodb-by-date), [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44576855/query-dynamodb-by-date-range) and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35963243/how-to-query-dynamodb-by-date-range-key-with-no-obvious-hash-key).

I hope this helps you.